# can't download file when name is like = зураг.doc i think the problem is charset but i really don't know fully yet and anyone have solution

Tags: android, file, download

This is file download Code

` String msg= attach.getName();
    byte [] b = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String v = new String( b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

```
String fileUrl = attach.getFilePath() + "/" + attach.getName();
String fileName = attach.getName();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + attach.getName());
if (file.exists()) {
    openFile(fileName);
} else {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // FILE permission has not been granted.
        requestFilePermission();

    } else {
        // FILE permissions is already available, show the FILE download.
        Log.i(TAG, "FILE permission has already been granted. Downloading FILE.");

        fileUrl = Utils.getUrl(context.getApplicationContext()) + fileUrl;
        fileUrl = fileUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fileUrl));
        request.setDescription(vattach.getName());
        request.setTitle(attach.getName());
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, v);

        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

`

Comment: How do you know it's because of name? Do you get any error message? (if yes -> [edit] question and append it)

Comment: when i change name like english it can download without problem so thought it's charset error